# Load JSON data instead of embedding it on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using [Mention.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Mention.js/) on my site, which populates a dropdown list of usernames when "@" is typed in an assigned textarea.

```
<textarea id="full"></textarea>
```

It's working great but the examples only show how to embed the JSON data on the actual page like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#full").mention({
            users: [{
                name: 'Rick Bahner',
                username: 'RickyBahner',
                image: 'http://placekitten.com/25/23'
            }, {
                name: 'Jacob Kelley',
                username: 'jakiestfu',
                image: 'http://placekitten.com/25/22'
            }, {
                name: 'John Doe',
                username: 'HackMurphy',
                image: 'http://placekitten.com/25/21'
            }, {
                name: 'Loud Mouth Burrito',
                username: 'Loudmouthfoods',
                image: 'http://placekitten.com/21/20'
            }]
        });

    });
</script>
```

I don't want to embed it, I have my JSON data stored in a separate file called **myresults.json** and I'd like to load that file instead.

I'm trying this but I don't think I'm doing it right as it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#full").mention({source: 'myresults.json'})
});
```

**EDIT**
Here is my updated call, thanks to Eric :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('myresults.json', function(__data){
    $("#full").mention({source:__data.users})
});
});
</script>
```

But it's still not working so I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1kbh70m/) with both embedded and JSON load methods. Maybe somebody can work out why the JSON version isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load a JSON file this way:

```
    $.getJSON('sample.json', function(__data){
        $("#full").mention({source:__data})
    });
```

Edit to match your file:

```
$.getJSON('https://res.cloudinary.com/d3ep/raw/upload/v1440597312/myresults_yod9qs.json', function(__data){
    console.log(__data);
});
```

Comment: Although I'm sure what you've written is correct it's still not working. If you look at the embedded <script> code you'll see that the json array is being wrapped in an option called 'users'. How would I formulate your code so that sample.json is wrapped in that option? ie: users: sample.json

Comment: {source:__data.users}, also you need to add quotes in JSON like {"users"':[{"name":"Rich"}] etc.

Comment: Yep my JSON is returning as you mentioned but it's still not working? <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON('myresults.json', function(__data){
        $("#ajax").mention({source:__data.users})
    });
 });
</script>

Comment: Please add your JSON data/document to you original post

Comment: Ahh I think I may have discovered the problem.. It looks like the script will only work if the JSON is formatted like this : name: 'Rick Bahner' where my json is returning "name:" "RickBahner"

Comment: I've added the JSON output as a pasetbin link. Sorry man, thanks for your help I really appreciate it

Comment: I'm starting to think that this can't be done with JSON? Re-reading your second comment and looking at the original embed code the script is just using a javascript array and not a JSON array. Is that correct?

Comment: Copied-pasted your JSON here and it loads just fine. You removed "users" so now simply use {source:__data} where __data is an array

Comment: i've created a fiddle with both methods and the JSON stored on my CDN, maybe you can see why the JSON version isn't working easier from there? - https://jsfiddle.net/g1kbh70m/

Comment: It works here, see edit to my post. Your fiddle has too many bugs, unusable (multi document ready,  __data.users etc)

Comment: thanks for all of your help bro. I still can't get it working so I'm trying a different approach. I just don't think that this jQuery based script likes the JSON format. I've marked your question as correct as what you suggested is in fact correct, but sadly this solution doesn't work in my situation.